# Static member constraint for op_addition

Tags: f#

I am trying to reinvent `List.fold`, `List.reduce`, and `List.sum` using pointfree `inline` functions for the sake of learning. Here is what I had:

```
let flip f y x = f x y

let rec fold folder seed = function
    | [] -> seed
    | h :: t -> fold folder (folder seed h) t

let inline reduce< ^a when ^a : (static member Zero : ^a) > : 
    (^a -> ^a -> ^a) -> ^a list -> ^a =
    flip fold LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero

let inline sum< ^a when 
            ^a : (static member (+) : ^a * ^a -> ^a) and 
            ^a : (static member Zero : ^a)> : ^a list -> ^a = 
    reduce (+)
           // ^ Compile error here
```

I know such verbose type constraints are not frequently used in F# but I am trying to learn so please bear with me.

I got a very cryptic compile error which I do not understand:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a -> 'a -> 'a 
but given a
    'a -> 'b -> 'c     
A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when ( ^a or  ^?269978) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^?269978 ->  ^?269979)' 
A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when ( ^a or  ^?269978) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^?269978 ->  ^?269979)' 
val ( + ) : x:'T1 -> y:'T2 -> 'T3 (requires member ( + )) 
Full name: Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.( + ) 
Overloaded addition operator
x: The first parameter. 
y: The second parameter.
```

What should I add to satisfy the compiler?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem because even `reduce` doesn't compile for me. i've got *expected `'a -> 'b -> 'a -> 'a` but given `('c -> 'd -> 'c) -> 'c -> 'd list -> 'c` The type `'a` does not match the type `'b -> 'c -> 'b`* pointing at **fold**

Comment: BTW, the F# implementation of List.reduce fails on empty lists, and doesn't need a GenericZero. For example, you can define reduce like this: let rec reduce op = function | [] -> failwith "empty" | [x] -> x  | h :: t -> op h (reduce op t)

Comment: @Sehnsucht sorry that's my typo, I have add type annotations to fix the compile error at `reduce`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way of doing exactly as you want, because there's no way I know of to invoke a statically constrained static member in pointfree style. Note that you are not invoking `(+)` of `^a` and the compiler does not know how to figure that out... if you are happy using a inner helper function, you can do:

```
let inline sum< ^a
    when ^a : (static member (+) : ^a -> ^a -> ^a) and
         ^a : (static member Zero : ^a) > : ^a list -> ^a =
    let add x y = (^a : (static member (+) : ^a -> ^a -> ^a) (x, y))
    reduce add
```

Note the warning

> warning FS0077: Member constraints with the name 'op_Addition' are given special status by the F# compiler as certain .NET types are implicitly augmented with this member. This may result in runtime failures if you attempt to invoke the member constraint from your own code.

and indeed:

`sum [1; 2; 3]` leads to

> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
>        at FSI_0005.it@15-1.Invoke(Int32 x, Int32 y) in ...

But if you change `sum` to:

```
let inline sum list =
    reduce (+) list

sum [1; 2; 3] // 6
```

Answer (score 3):

My unhelpful answer would be: don't do that.  Inline definitions are only intended to be syntactic functions, so you're not supposed to define them in a point-free way.  For instance, compare the results of trying to evaluate the following three lines:

```
let inline identity = id
let inline identity : ^a -> ^a = id
let inline identity< ^a> : ^a -> ^a = id
```

Only the final one compiles, (technically this is because it's a "type function", which is basically a function that's passed an invisible `unit` value behind the scenes to allow it to be treated as a generic value).

However, if you insist on doing things this way, then one way to "fix" it is to make `(+)` less generic; by default the arguments and return type can be of different types and the constraints introduced by this flexibility are part of what's confusing the compiler.  Here's one fix:

```
let inline reduce< ^a, 'b  when  ^a : (static member Zero : ^a)> : ( ^a -> 'b ->  ^a) -> ('b list ->  ^a) =
    flip fold LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero

let inline (+) (x:^a) (y:^a) = x + y

let inline sum< ^a
                 when ^a : (static member ( + ) :  ^a * ^a -> ^a)
                  and ^a : (static member Zero : ^a)> : ^a list -> ^a =
    reduce (+)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Vandroiy, the given reduce function doesn't compile for me. I think what you wanted for your `reduce` function is actually:

```
let inline reduce< ^a when ^a : (static member Zero : ^a) > : ((^a -> ^a -> ^a) -> ^a list -> ^a)  =
    flip fold LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
```

Doing that I was able to replicate your given error.

However, when I changed the `sum` function to compile by using a simple test function:

```
let inline sum< ^a when 
        ^a : (static member Zero : ^a) and
        ^a : (static member (+) : (^a -> ^a -> ^a))  > : ^a list -> ^a = 
    reduce (fun i j -> i)
```

and trying to call `sum [1..10]` results in `The type 'int' does not support the operator 'get_op_Addition'`. So I'm not sure this methodology will even work.

EDIT: Thanks for the hints of CaringDev, I fixed the get_op_Addition error. This seems to work. Though as to why, I'm pretty baffled since `'b` is just `^a` in disguise...

```
let inline sum< ^a when 
        ^a : (static member Zero : ^a) and
        ^a : (static member (+) : ^a -> ^a -> ^a)  > : ^a list -> ^a =
    let inline add (x:'b) (y:'b) = (+) x y
    reduce add
```

Comment: (a.k.a. Vandroiy) I seem to have a new nickname ^^

Comment: Vandroiy had an answer posted, then he deleted it so now you must suffice haha.

Comment: This error originates from the superfluous parentheses for the `+` constraint: these make the compiler believe you want a member to *get* (i.e. returning) the `+` function.

Comment: @CaringDev I didn't even make it till that (+) constraint ; it's unlikely an untyped yet code that gives me that error

Comment: @Sehnsucht, yes, yours is due to an error in the question. I started deleting all annotations... So didn't even notice :-) @Ringils `The type 'int' does not support ...` is due to `static member (+) : (^a -> ^a -> ^a)` instead of `static member (+) : ^a -> ^a -> ^a`

Comment: @CaringDev thanks for telling me that. that's some strange behavior.